# Не линкуются *.c и *.cpp файлы в проекте

Tags: c++, c, cmake

День добрый!

Осваиваю cmake. Не могу понять почему вместе не собираются исходники *.cpp и *.c

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(task2_cmake LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(task2_cmake main.cpp src/lib.c)
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "src/lib.h"

int main()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

**lib.h**

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void print();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // LIB_H
```

**lib.c**

```
#include "lib.h"

void print()
{
    int a;
}
```

Собираю из QtCreator
Выдаёт ошибку: undefined reference to `print'

Обертка `#include "src/lib.h"` в `extern "C"` ни к чему не приводит

Comment: `extern "C"` тут не к чему, а `lib.c` следует переименовать в `lib.cpp` коли собираете как С++ код

Comment: как раз я хочу избежать переименования в *.cpp

Comment: Ну тогда делайте два проекта - один с языком С, другой с языком С++ и линкуйте их.

Comment: решение было вот таким: project(task2_cmake LANGUAGES C CXX) или project(task2_cmake)

Comment: Если это решило проблему, пожалуйста, ответе на собственный вопрос и пометьте ответ как решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было вот таким:

```
project(task2_cmake LANGUAGES C CXX)
```

или

```
project(task2_cmake)
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавление в `CMakeLists.txt` что проект поддерживает язык C

```
project(task2_cmake LANGUAGES CXX C)
```

Answer (score 0):

добавлю пояснение, CMake если у него не указан язык проекта по умолчанию "инициализирует" С и C++ компиляторы, находит в системе, проверяет что они компилируют и прописывает во временных файлах информацию о них, если явно задать только один из языков, cmake сделает это только для него и не будет ни чего знать об остальных. Соответственно когда он встретит файл .с в проекте он попытается отдать в команду конторой нет в билд системе, даже если используется один и тот же исполняемый файл для компиляции.